# Unbound Local Error I can't solve

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a conversions calculator and I believe I have it correct but I keep getting a

"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'F2C' referenced before assignment"

Does this mean I'm using the wrong key? Or does it mean the order I wrote the functions is the problem?
The beginning section of the code works properly when I ran it but I can't figure out what the error is trying to tell me.

Here is the section of the code:

```
def select():
displayMenu();
choice = input ('Enter choice number:')
if (choice == 1):
    F2C();
elif (choice == 2):
    C2F();
elif (choice == 3):
    I2C();
elif (choice == 4):
    C2I();
elif (choice == 5):
    G2L();
elif (choice == 6):
    L2G();
elif (choice == 7):
    Y2M();
elif (choice == 8):
    M2Y();
elif (choice == 9):
    P2K();
elif (choice == 10):
    K2P();
```

Am I using incorrect syntax?

Comment: Is this the whole function? You probably have an assignment to `F2C` somewhere in the function. Check your indentation, and make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: All those extra semicolons and parentheses aren't incorrect enough to confuse the interpreter… but they are certainly enough to confuse any human reader who expects Python to look like Python rather than C.

Comment: Also, show us the complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: @abarnert O.O My brain was set in C-mode until I read your comment.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit about something (not related to the question but good to know) that has been mentioned -- Python does not require lines to end with semicolons `;`. In your code, it doesn't look like it'll cause a problem, since the interpreter will allow you to end lines with them, but it's not good Python style.

Comment: You probably need to convert `choice` to an `int` since the `input` function will return a string. `choice = int(choice)`

Comment: @jramirez: I assume this is Python 2.x, in which case the `input` function will evaluate the string as an arbitrary Python expression and therefore return `1`. (Assuming the user enters `1`, that is… if the user enters `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` that's another story…)

Comment: @pandubear Ya I just tested it out and the semi colons didn't effect it but I appreciate the tip. I wasn't aware. Ill keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: @abarnert you're right.

Comment: You also don't need (and shouldn't add) parentheses around `if` conditions and the like; just do `elif choice == 9:`. (By the way, the reason the semicolons don't hurt anything is that in Python, they're used to separate statements on the same line. So, when you write `M2Y();`, that's two statements—one is `M2Y()`, and the other is empty, which is legal but not very useful.)

Comment: @abarnert Appreciate the corrections. Ill drop the parentheses and avoid adding extras.

Comment: What don't understand is how you can define a var at the module level (outside a def) and have no issues, when var is referenced in def function in the module. The moment you call a function in that module from outside it, you get his issue. It's defined outside a function. So beyond defining a variable as global how else can I get Python to initialise the module vars when called from outside it. It seems really funky and not well explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `F2C` isn't defined anywhere that you can access.

That's obvious in the fragment you showed us… but in your real code, presumably it's defined *somewhere*. The problem is that wherever it's defined, it's not in this module's globals. Most likely either:

- You defined it in another module, and did `import other_module`—in which case the function is named `other_module.F2C`, not `F2C`.
- You defined it in another module, and didn't even import that module, in which case the function isn't there at all.
- You accidentally defined it inside some other function (by getting your indentation wrong), meaning it's local to that function rather than global to your whole module.
- You assigned some other value to `F2C` later in the function. Again, probably accidentally (by getting your indentation wrong). Python will guess that you want to use the *local variable*, rather than the *global function* whenever you say `F2C` in this function.  But the local variable hasn't been assigned yet.

The fact that it's specifically an `UnboundLocalError` rather than a `NameError` is a useful clue: it means Python thinks this should be a local variable rather than a global, which almost certainly means you either defined it or assigned a value to `F2C` *later in the same function*… most likely because you indented a bunch of the rest of the script inside this function.

Comment: THANKS!! That was it! I defined the functions in the same module but I defined it within another function, getting the indentation wrong like you said, appreciate it!

Comment: @FOTG: A lot of things in Python that don't seem like indentation errors really are—just like a lot of errors in C that make no sense are actually caused by a missing `}` 300 lines away.

Comment: Im beginning to understand that. Ill be sure to proofread over and over again the next time I have a problem like this.

Comment: `F2C` is defined otherwise it would be `NameError`. Moreover, it is defined *locally* (*not* other module or something like that). It is just [defined *after* it is used in the code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034020/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's already the whole point of the last paragraph.

Comment: @abarnert: yeah, the paragraph was added after I've answered.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: No it wasn't. Your comment is 42 minutes ago; the answer was last edited 44 minutes ago. (And that last edit was just a minor revision of the last paragraph, which already existed.)

Comment: @abarnert: look at the timestamp on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034020/4279)

Answer (score 1):

`UnboundLocalError` means that `F2C` is used *before it is defined locally* i.e.,

- it is not defined *before it is used* anywhere (globally, locally)
- it *is* defined *locally* somewhere *after*

Example:

```
def f():
    print(a) # assuming there is no global `a`; it raises UnboundLocalError
    a = 1
```